# Staging Artifacts in Java

Tags: java

Java Artifacts are often staged through different statuses until they are eventually released, so having alpha-status, beta-status, release-candidate-status, and, finally, release status (as an example).

I know that Sonatype Nexus offers you possibilities to stage artifacts, so that they can be pushed from one stage to the next after passing tests or after getting approval from the authorized staff. Are there other interesting options on the market?

Answer (score 0):

[Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) is very good. I’ve only used it for work, unsure if there’s a free version available.

Comment: Could you add more information about staging in Artifactory?